# Finding the Number of Zeros Between the Decimal Point and the First Nonzero Digit

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is as follows:

> The expansion of $(\frac{2}{3})^{30}$ begins with $0.000...$ . How many zeros are there between the decimal point and the first nonzero digit? In the expansion of $(\frac{2}{3})^{1000000}$ how many zeros are there between the decimal point and the first nonzero digit?

I used my calculator to solve for the value of $(\frac{2}{3})^{30}$ and I got that there are $5$ numbers that are in between the decimal point and the first nonzero digit. I thought that maybe taking $\log((\frac{2}{3})^{1000000})$ for which I would get $-176091.2591$. I know that if you have $10^n$, then number of digits that that value will have is going to be $n + 1$. I was thinking that maybe I can use the same principle in answering this question because $10^{-176091.2591} = (\frac{2}{3})^{1000000}$, so there would be $176092$  digits. If I am wrong, can someone please correct me or help me? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How many zeros before the 1 in $10^{-2}?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers with $n$ zeros between the decimal point and the first nonzero lie in the interval $[10^{-(n+1)}, 10^{-n})$. So given a number $x$, the number of zeros is $\lceil - \log_{10} x \rceil - 1$.

Indeed $\log_{10}((2/3)^{30})=-5.28$ which gives you the $5$ zeros.
Similarly, $\log_{10}((2/3)^{10^6}) = - 176091.3$ which gives you $176091$ zeros.

Comment: That makes so much sense! However, as what @saulspatz asked about  how many zeros before 1 in $10^{-2}$, I know that there is only one zero between that 1 and the decimal point. However, base-10 logarithm of $10^{-2}$ is $-2$, so why is it that there's only one number between 1 and the decimal point, but the log gives me 2 zeros?

Comment: @geo_freak I've edited my answer

Comment: I see, but since you have added that you must subtract 1, then for $(\frac{2}{3})^{30}$, there would be 4 zeros instead of 5?

Comment: @geo_freak No, the floor function changed to the ceiling function; it is $\lceil -(-5.28) \rceil - 1 = 6 - 1 = 5$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray}
0.1&\le&10^n\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^m<1\\
-1&\le&\log\left[10^n\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right]<0\\
-1&\le&n+m\log\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)<0\\
-1-m\log\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)&\le&n<-m\log\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)
\end{eqnarray}

So the number $n$ of zeros between the decimal and the first non-zero digit of $\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^m$ is

$$ n=\left\lceil-1-m\log\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right\rceil $$

or, alternately

$$ n=\left\lfloor-m\log\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right\rfloor $$